# PHP para de funcionar sem explicação no IIS com FastCGI

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

Recentemente atualizei um site que estava escrito em ASP clássico no IIS do Windows 2008 Server, troquei a programação do site para PHP e mantive rodando no IIS via FastCGI, enquanto o site estava em homologação não tive problema algum, mas ao colocar em produção, pelo menos duas ou três vezes ao dia o PHP para de funcionar (As áreas do site que ainda estão em ASP continuam funcionando, apenas as páginas feitas em PHP param), não aparece erro algum no navegador (apenas dá timeout) ou no LOG do PHP. A única solução para voltar ao ar é reiniciar o IIS.
Já atualizei do PHP 5.4 para o 5.6 e o problema persiste.
Como o problema só começou a acontecer depois que o site já entrou em produção, achei que podia ser algum gargalo de hardware, porém, quando acontece o servidor esta sempre com apenas 5 a 10% de uso do processamento e a memória nunca chega a 50%. Fora que já chegou a acontecer as 02h30 da manhã, quando o site tem quase nenhum acesso.

Seguem algumas imagens com as configurações básicas do PHP no IIS e também o arquivo php.ini:
[image: Configurações básicas]
[image: Extensões instaladas e habilitadas]

E aqui esta um link para ver o arquivo "PHP.ini" completo:
[php.ini](http://www.pensadigital.com.br/stackoverflow/php_ini.txt)

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema ou tem ideia de qual o motivo de isso acontecer?

Obrigado!

Comment: Habilite todas as mensagens de erro e log do PHP. Verifique também logs do IIS e eventos do Windows.

Comment: OK.. habilitei o LOG do IIS e vou verificar hoje, porém, no LOG do PHP, não tem nenhum erro nos horários que acontecem que indicam o motivo.

Comment: olá, assista esse vídeo que fiz a algum tempo veja se te ajuda https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKADgq_WqZ0